# How to force installation of standard-width blinds for window with nonstandard dimensions?

Tags: windows

I want to install blinds on a window that has a `27.5`-inch width. But it looks as though `27.5`inches is not a standard width; it's easy to find widths of `23, 27, 29, 30`, I don't see `27.5` inch blinds anywhere. I did just find [these 27 inch blinds](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002VFHK4Q), however. Is there a DIY way to customize `27` inch blinds so that they can be installed on a `27.5`-inch wide window? 
Alternatively, would buying `28-29` inch blinds, and sawing them down to `27.5` inches work?

Please remember to keep answers specific to the problem at hand. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those 27 inch blinds you link to are *top mount* and will fit in a 27.5 inch opening without modification. But there are also *side mount* ones that would also work but you would need to add a 1/4 inch shim to both sides or a 1/2 inch shim to one side.

Most blinds can't be simply cut down in width except those that are designed to be cut to length.

Comment: I see unfinished wood shims are available, but the color would contrast with my white walls. What about plummer's putty?